# phpmyadmin accessing IP's database, not localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Oddly i thought more people would have asked this.

So i have set up 2 phpmyadmins locally. One pointing to locahost and the other, on its own local url to an outside IP address.

The problem, when going to my second outside phpmyadmin it still reports that i am connected to localhost `User: iuworkhorse.com@localhost`

and the databases i have access to confirm this.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'asosmidseasonsal';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '109.XXX.XXX.XXX';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3306;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'it knows which user name i have logged in with';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'blahblah';
```

No ideas what to do about this, also i know that phpmyadmin is reading from this config file i have set up as it reads which user i am logging in as

Comment: What do you mean by two phpmyadmins? Have you actually got two separate phpmyadmin folders or do you have one phpmyadmin with two servers configured?

Comment: 2 separate folders locally. With 2 separate urls for each version running.

Comment: maybe you have to start a new session? Try restarting your browser before you switch between phpmyadmins

Comment: thanks for the help, but this isn't the case. As i see different settings in my ip'd version of phpmyadmin. None the less, i tried it in IE and it was the same problem. bummer :(

Comment: Using cookies for authentication is probably related. Do you logout before restarting the browser? There may be a delayed expiry. Does it happen if you use two *different* browsers (eg IE and Firefox) simultaneously?

Comment: Hummm, i guess nobody has any clue on whats up anymore :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tunnel the external DB to a different port, such as 3307. Set one phpMyAdmin installation with the default configuration to work locally, and the second one, change the port to 3307. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After a long long disappointing time, i realised that there is no way to do what i was after. I ended up mysql workbench to connect to 2 different ip's at the same time.

Comment: Have you found a good alternative to MySQL Workbeng? I really dislike the former's interface..

Comment: indeed, I HATE IT! But sadly no, i could not find an alternative... Sorry :(

Comment: I am trying to set up phpMyAdmin to work with the tunneled DB, however I cannot seem to get phpMyAdmin to connect (Workbench works). If you see my question and hopefully can assist me, that'd be great! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003846/connect-to-tunneled-db-through-phpmyadmin

Comment: how'd you do it? Add it as an answer maybe?