# Connect to tunneled DB through phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, tunnel

So I've tunneled the DB to port 3307 on 127.0.0.1 .. I can connect to the database and do whatever I want by using Ubuntu's MySQL Workbench, however I really dislike the interface of the GUI so I want to use the ol'friend phpMyAdmin.

The connection parameters I am using are:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3307;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']= 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'myDBuser';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'myDBpass';
```

When I go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, select my server from the dropdown and click Go, the following errors are displayed:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'myDBuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

My login details are correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check, double check and then triple check username and password. To be sure, temporarily revert back to the default port (3306) and see if it works.

Comment: did you try doing this in terminal manually? `mysql -u myDBuser -p --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3307`

Comment: 1337holiday, I tried it and it didn't work, it returned the same error as phpMyAdmin, however, using the MySQL workbench works flawlessly. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by removing the password and logging in with no password. I don't know why it can log in without proving a password, but its working now. Thank you all for your help!